# Update API Data from a "Sub-view"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been trying to minimize the use of API Calls in my weather app project to just one API Call. By doing this it seems that my weather information no longer updates from the `@State` variable I use to decide what day of the week to get the weather data for. I have tried `print` the variable labelled `dayNumber` for each day but it is printing the right numbers the only problem is the data is not matching up its all showing the current date (dayNumber: 0). Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as I have only been coding for a few months

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Here is basically how I've structured my code

Main View

```
struct HomeView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var data: WeatherAPI

ForecastModuleView()

}.onAppear(perform: data.loadData)
```

ForecastModuleView

```
struct ForecastModuleView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var data: WeatherAPI

    HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    
        Spacer()
                    
        ColumnView(dayNum: 0)
                          
        ColumnView(dayNum: 1)
                  
        ColumnView(dayNum: 2)
                  
        ColumnView(dayNum: 3)
                  
        ColumnView(dayNum: 4)

                    
        Spacer()
                    
}
```

ColumnView

```
struct ColumnView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var data: WeatherAPI
    @State var dayNum: Int
    func dayNumFunc() {
        
        data.dayNumber = self.dayNum
        print(data.dayNumber)
        
    }

    var body: some View {
                    
        ZStack {
            
            ModuleBackgroundView(width: 200, height: 200, cornerRadius: 30)
                    
            VStack {
                                                    
                if data.dailyDate == "Today" {
                    
                    Text("\(data.dailyDate.uppercased())")
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Heavy", size: 24))
                    .foregroundColor(.offblack)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                    
                }
                    
                else {
                    
                    Text("\(data.dailyDate.uppercased())")
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Bold", size: 24))
                    .foregroundColor(.offblack)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                    
                }
                
                if data.dailyIcon == "minus" {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "\(data.dailyIcon)")
                        .foregroundColor(.offblack)
                        .font(.system(size: 60, weight: .bold))
                        .padding(5)
                    
                }
                
                else if data.dailyIcon == "cloud.fill" || data.dailyIcon == "smoke.fill" {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "\(data.dailyIcon)")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.system(size: 60, weight: .bold))
                        .padding(15)
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "\(data.dailyIcon)")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .font(.system(size: 60, weight: .bold))
                        .padding(5)
                    
                }
                
                HStack {

                    Text("\(Int(data.dailyHigh.rounded()))")
                        .font(.custom("Avenir Next", size: 24))
                        .foregroundColor(.offblack)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)

                    Text("\(Int(data.dailyLow.rounded()))")
                        .font(.custom("Avenir Next", size: 24))
                        .foregroundColor(.offblack)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)

                }
            }.animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 400, damping: 20))
            
            if data.dailyDate == "Now" {
                
                if data.currentRain == 100 {
                    
                    RainIndicator(rainPercent: "90")
                    
                }
                
                else if data.currentRain > 0.25 {
                    RainIndicator(rainPercent: "\(Int((data.currentRain*10).rounded()*10))")
                    .offset(x: 90, y: -90)
                }
            }
            
            else {
                
                if data.dailyRain == 100 {
                    
                    RainIndicator(rainPercent: "90")
                    
                }
                
                else if data.dailyRain > 0.25 {

                    RainIndicator(rainPercent: "\(Int((data.dailyRain*10).rounded()*10))")
                    .offset(x: 90, y: -90)

                }
                
            }
            
        }.onAppear(perform: dayNumFunc)

        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `WeatherAPI` object stores the weather for one day only (specified by `data.dayNumber`). That's why all your ColumnViews display the same day.

This code (and especially `dayNumFunc`) changes the `dayNumber` in the WeatherAPI):

```
struct ColumnView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: WeatherAPI
    @State var dayNum: Int

    func dayNumFunc() {
        data.dayNumber = self.dayNum
        print(data.dayNumber)
    }
```

but as all ColumnViews are changing the *same* WeatherAPI, in the end your WeatherAPI will still be displaying the weather for just one day.

---

The solution may be to store an array of forecasts instead of one single forecast and in the view access this array by index.

Instead of:

```
data.dailyIcon
data.dailyHigh
...
```

it could be:

```
data.forecasts[0].dailyIcon
data.forecasts[0].dailyHigh
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I understand now why it's doing that. I'll try this out and let you knows if it works.